# Pregnancy complications and performance drop

Tags: performance, spain, pregnancy

A coworker announced his wife was pregnant a couple of months ago. We work remotely for a small tech startup in Spain. He is a great employee and I think the manager knows it: he is devoted and recently identified a key issue that has to be addressed immediately.

Today he told me they are having complications with the pregnancy and there is risk of miscarriage. He has to wait until next week to know it for sure. Understandably, he told me he was feeling unwell and having difficulties in concentrating due to the pregnancy issues.

He asked me for advice. This is what we came up with:

- Talking to the manager and explain the situation with the pregnancy, in hopes of reducing pressure and that a *temporary* performance drop could be expected. The manager already knows that he is having a baby.
- Taking some days off.

I am just a newbie, is this good advice? Did I forget something?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your answers, this experience is very valuable.

Given that many people mention that PTOs (paid time off) are the way to go: unfortunately, they are called "días de asuntos propios" in Spain and are **not** guaranteed by law for the private sector.

The manager agreed to let him have some anyway!

Comment: *"not guaranteed..."* - surely Spain implements the EU working time directive, which requires 4 weeks PTO?

Answer (score 10):

Quite a sensible topic, I personally wouldn't disclose a possible miscarriage of my partner to my manager or HR, especially without her consent since this is ***VERY*** private medical information.

Maybe taking some PTO or holiday-days is the best advice..

Additionally your coworker could talk to their manager and state some vague family/medical issue and ask for less work-load, but since the manager is already aware that he'll (hopefully) be a father in the near future, the manager might add up the numbers.

Edit from the comments:

> *"Mm so is disclosing pregnancy related info with the manager not a good practice? I am usually very careful when talking about health and family but I'll add pregnancy to the list :)"*

There's always the risk of a miscarriage:

> Spontaneous abortion, also known as miscarriage, is defined as the loss of pregnancy less than 20 weeks gestation. The American College of Obstetricians and Gynecologists (ACOG) estimates it is the most common form of pregnancy loss. It is estimated that as many as 26% of all pregnancies end in miscarriage and up to 10% of clinically recognized pregnancies.

-> [Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK532992/) (stats for US)

Especially in the first 3-4 months of a pregnancy, so I fully agree with you. But eventually - maybe 1-2 months or so to the due-date - he eventually wants to disclose the fact that he'll be a father soon in case he wants to take parental leave, which obviously needs to be considered by management in terms of replacement, shift of work-load and deadlines..

**Clarification PTO vs holiday days:**

Sometimes, these terms are used interchangeably. But they’re not exactly the same. There are many differences between PTO and vacation — from the level of flexibility that comes with these two types of leave to the difficulty of keeping track of them. Jury duties, bereavement, paternity/maternity leave, volunteer work etc. are qualified reasons for PTO.

-> [Source](https://clockify.me/blog/managing-teams/pto-vs-vacation/#:%7E:text=PTO%20is%20an%20abbreviation%20for,these%20leaves%20are%20treated%20separately)

Obviously the above mentioned points depend on your local labor-laws and regulations as well as special agreements with the employer.

Comment: PTO - best thing to do.

Comment: Mm so is disclosing pregnancy related info with the manager not a good practice? I am usually very careful when talking about health and family but I'll add pregnancy to the list :)

Comment: @BrainOverflow Pls see my edit..

Comment: Ouch, not sure if I am getting right the last edit. I am (unfortunately) aware that a miscarriage is not so uncommon. So I think your suggestion is disclosing the pregnancy a couple of months before the baby is born but no earlier, since there is always a risk. I am getting it right?

Comment: I would have phrased it differently: I think the definition and detailed statistics about miscarriages are off-topic (just saying that 20% of pregnancies are at risk would be enough), and I would not have quoted my comment. But thanks anyway and I will keep the advice in mind

Comment: @BrainOverflow You are welcome! BTW, it's advised here and other SE-sites to back up claims/stats by valid sources. Additionally, quoting comments when adding relevant information for the OP is purposeful for context and clarifiaction - hence the quotes and source of the stats.. ;)

Comment: One can simply say "complications with the pregnancy" if one does want to explain; folks mostly understand the implied range of risks and should be sympathetic. But PTO is certainly simplest.

Comment: @keshlam _"folks mostly understand the implied range of risks and should be sympathetic."_ I agree - In an ideal world, yes.. But some might start gossiping etc. Point being:  It is confidential medical information of the coworkers wife and shouldn't be disclosed if not needed, especially without the wife's consent.

Comment: Yes, this is not to be discussed unless the co-worker chooses to discuss it. The conversation, if any, should be between the co-worker and their manager, with an understanding that it will be kept private until/unless the manager is told otherwise.. I thought that could be assumed, but apparently not. . I've never understood the attraction of gossip anyway.

Comment: @iLuvLogix no gossiping in my case. We all know the deal and get along very well.

Comment: @BrainOverflow That's good to hear you are in such a pleasant work-environment ;)

Comment: Thank you :D on the other hand, unfortunately we do not have PTOs in Spain. They are called "días de asuntos propios" and they are only guaranteed by law for the Public Sector :(

Comment: @BrainOverflow I just read that you get at least 22 paid days off for holiday or the like - I don't quite understand you..

Comment: @iLuvLogix as far as I understand, PTOs and holidays are different. We have 22 holidays and people on the public sector get 6 extra days per year for PTOs. But yeah that could work to some extent too

Comment: @BrainOverflow See my clarification in my answer in the last paragraph..

Comment: @iLuvLogix ah I see. So PTO = vacation days + other paid leave days, thanks for the clariffication. Anyways, I think in Spain having a PTO would mean having 1 less holiday on summer (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

> I am just a newbie, is this good advice?

These are ok options, nothing obviously wrong here. In the future, make sure you only engage if you feel that you have good and informed advice. If you need to shoot from the hip, defer or decline: "Sorry, this not my area of expertise" or "Let me think about it for a bit" are good answers too.

The problem here is: if you give advice and it goes side-ways it will backfire on you, specifically if you didn't do your homework properly upfront. Good advice should be based on research, data and experience, not on gut feel.

> Did I forget something?

Yes. These type of situations are entangled with local labor laws and company policies. That's what HR is for. If you have a half way decent HR department, your coworker should approach them and discuss the pros/cons of the different options which could include PTO, temporary part time, just cutting them some slack, medical or family leave of absence, etc.

HR is also better at keeping confidentialities and create accommodation for "personal issues" without anyone else having to know what this issue is. HR also will make sure that any action taken is fully compliant with laws and rules.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your answers, this experience is very valuable.

Given that many people mention that PTOs (paid time off) are the way to go: unfortunately, they are called "días de asuntos propios" in Spain and are **not** guaranteed by law for the private sector.

The manager agreed to let him have some either way!

Comment: I agree with your first & second paragraph - therefore the upvote, but I think you overestimate the confidentiality of HR departments and forget about the fact that HR pull their ropes for the benefit of the company, and not for the employees..

Comment: It always surprising to me how the role of HR is misunderstood.  HR is neither your friend nor your enemy. Their job is to KNOW all the rules and make sure everyone is COMPLIANT. HR will not disclose anything internally if  they are legally not allowed to do so. In most legislations that includes medical information.

Comment: Thank you, I like the "let me think about it for a bit" approach. On the other hand, I do **not** trust HR in my company. They are doing a bad job with bureaucratic stuff, they are one of the main shareholders of the company and they are pressing the manager for results (not me). They will definitively act on behalf of the company.

Comment: I messed up the edit, and I do not know how to revert it omg...